# How to use a dynamic path with Nuxt-Content?

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify, nuxtjs3, nuxt-content

I'm trying to display a document of a Nuxt-Content folder with a dynamic path :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const n = ref(1)
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <ContentDoc 
      v-slot="{ doc }"
      :path="'collection/' + n" 
    >
      <ContentRenderer :value="doc" />
    </ContentDoc>
    <div @click="n++">
      Click-me !
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

It's working perfectly fine in development, however after deploying the application (with nuxt generate) on Netlify, the document is never found after the click event.

Does someone know why it is happening and how to make it work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you provide some more information to try to help you? Is it working locally in production mode? Is there a specific log in the netlify deployed page in the dev tools?